# The requested resource does not support http method 'GET' when calling action returning boolean

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API where I have more than one get method in the controller. One of the controller methods returns true or flas - used as a validation of employee id

Below is my code:

My repository class:

```
public class myRepository
{

    public myClasses.Type[] GetAllTypes()
    {

        return new myClasses.Type[]
        {
            new myClasses.Type 
            {
                typeId="1",
                typeVal = "New"
            },
            new myClasses.Type 
            {
                typeId="2",
                typeVal = "Old"
            }
       };

    }

    public myClasses.Employee[] GetAllEmployees()
    {

        return new myClasses.Employee[]
        {
            new myClasses.Employee 
            {
                empId="111111",
                empFName = "Jane",
                empLName="Doe"
            },
            new myClasses.Employee 
            {
                empId="222222",
                empFName = "John",
                empLName="Doe"
            }
       };

    }

    public bool VerifyEmployeeId(string id)
    {

        myClasses.Employee[] emp = new myClasses.Employee[]
        {
            new myClasses.Employee 
            {
                empId="111111",
                empFName = "Jane",
                empLName="Doe"
            },
            new myClasses.Employee 
            {
                empId="222222",
                empFName = "John",
                empLName="Doe"
            }
       };

        for (var i = 0; i <= emp.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (emp[i].empId == id)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and my model class:

```
public class myClasses
{

    public class Employee
    {
        public string empId { get; set; }
        public string empFName { get; set; }
        public string empLName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Type
    {
        public string typeId { get; set; }
        public string typeVal { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and here is my controller:

```
public class myClassesController : ApiController
{
    private myRepository empRepository;

    public myClassesController()
    {
        this.empRepository = new myRepository();
    }

    public myClasses.Type[] GetTypes()
    {
        return empRepository.GetAllTypes();
    }

    public myClasses.Employee[] GetEmployees()
    {
        return empRepository.GetAllEmployees();
    }

    public bool VerifyEmployee(string id)
    {
        return empRepository.VerifyEmployeeId(id);
    }
}
```

Everything compiles fine but when I run it using

```
http://localhost:49358/api/myClasses/GetTypes
```

and that returns all the data in xml format. But when I run

```
http://localhost:49358/api/myClasses/VerifyEmployee/222222
```

I get an error "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'"

My WebAPIConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        // Uncomment the following line of code to enable query support for actions with an IQueryable or IQueryable<T> return type.
        // To avoid processing unexpected or malicious queries, use the validation settings on QueryableAttribute to validate incoming queries.
        // For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=279712.
        //config.EnableQuerySupport();

        // To disable tracing in your application, please comment out or remove the following line of code
        // For more information, refer to: http://www.asp.net/web-api
        config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? What am I doing wrong here? Are there better ways to do validations against data via Web API?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you do not need to create an Action only to verify your Employee, when you want to do any changes with this Employee, you can verify it in this Action, and with this you can save 1 extra request, for example:

```
[HttpPut]
public IHttpActionResult Update(EmployeeViewModel model)
{
    if(!empRepository.VerifyEmployeeId(model.Id))
        return BadRequest("Some error message");

    empRepository.Update(model);
    return Ok();
}
```

And in your return type you should use `IHttpActionResult` to use Http status code. Unless you need to return a Collection.

And if you need an Action to only verify the Employee, for any reason, you can do like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult VerifyEmployee(string id)
{
    var isValid = empRepository.VerifyEmployeeId(string id);

    return isValid ? Ok() : BadRequest("Some message");
}
```

### If you are using WebApi Version 1, try this:

```
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage Update(EmployeeViewModel model)
{
    if(!empRepository.VerifyEmployeeId(model.Id))
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    empRepository.Update(model);
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}

[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage VerifyEmployee(string id)
{
    var isValid = empRepository.VerifyEmployeeId(string id);

    return isValid ? new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) : new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

Comment: i cannot use the first example simply because i am not doing update, just checking if id is valid. As far as the second example goes, could you please explain why the IHttpActionRequest?  Also I get an error that namespace IHttpActionRequest cannot be found

Comment: Wich version of WebApi you're using? IHttpActionResult, comes with custom built in responses such as (Ok, BadRequest, NotFound, Unauthorized, Exception, Conflict, Redirect), with custom negotiated content, and still simplifies unit testing of your controller.

Comment: I am using version 4

Comment: You should see in Developer Tools (if you're using chrome), what it returns

Comment: I am using IE. How can I open the web api using Chrome?

Comment: Just open the url in CHrome and press F12, to see [developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/?hl=en#network)

Comment: Got it. In Chrome it says "Failed to load response data"

Comment: Could you take a print screen and upload the image?

Comment: I can do that but could you tell me first if I am looking at the right place. I am checking Network tab, then select the id value and response tab

Comment: Thats right, you should put a breakpoint in your Controller, and check if everything is working in there.

Comment: I actually got things working without changing mo code, just by adding HttpGet prefix